# (C++) Learning vectors - problems with coding/input stream termination/comparing vectors

Tags: c++, vector, terminate

I'm beginner learning my first programming language - C++ - from Bjarne Stroustrup's book "Programming Principles and Practice Using C++". Chapter 4 talks about vectors. Everything explained before I would get easily and code would always work properly, until now.

The code I write doesn't function at all. The following code was made for little exercise, where the input is read in and prints the words out, bleeping out the disliked ones.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {
    vector<string>text;
    string disliked = "cat";

    for (string word; cin >> word;) {       
        text.push_back(word);
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < text.size(); ++a) {
            if (text[a] != disliked) {
                cout << text[a] << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "BLEEP\n";
            }
        }
    keep_window_open();
}
```

My first idea was to create another vector, `vector<string>disliked ={"cat", ...}` , for disliked words, but then `if (text[x] != disliked)` didn't seem like a way of comparing elements from each vector (at least it was warning me about operator and operands mismatch). Is there a way for that?

But back to the code: with some modifications and without any disliked word in the input, the program would run sometimes. Still I can't manage to meet the main purpose. And perhaps, the actual mistake is in the input termination. Ctrl+Z doesn't work for me but just inputs a character. And somehow Ctrl+C happened to work properly (if there were no disliked words).

So here come the actual questions:

1. Is the code correct? (since I can't check it myself while I might have been terminating the input improperly entire time)
2. How can I terminate input any other way, considering that Ctrl+Z only adds a character to the input?
3. Is there a way of making this program work by comparing the "input" vector with the "disliked" vector?

Comment: Write the input in a file and execute: ./myprogram < file.in

Comment: Ctrl-D on linux machines marks end of a stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the code correct? (since I can't check it myself while I might have been terminating the input improperly entire time)

Seems to work for me.

> How can I terminate input any other way, considering that Ctrl+Z only adds a character to the input?

I use `Ctrl-D` to mark end of line.

> Is there a way of making this program work by comparing the "input" vector with the "disliked" vector?

Usually when you compare types (with `==` and `!=`) they have the same type (or the compiler can convert one type to the same type as the other type (but that's for the pedantic here; for beginners its best to think of comparison comparing objects of the same type)).

```
vector<string> text;
string         disliked = "cat";

// STUFF
if (text[x] != disliked) // disliked is a string
                         // text[x]  is a string (because we are accessing the `x` element.
```

If we change disliked to a vector:

```
vector<string> text;
vector<string> disliked = "cat";

// STUFF
if (text[x] != disliked) // disliked is a vector<string>
                         // text[x]  is a string
```

Since the types do not match they are hard to compare. So you need to loop over all the elements in disliked to see if you can find the word.

```
bool found = false;
for(std::size_t loop = 0; loop < disliked.size(); ++loop) {
    if (text[x] == disliked[loop) {  // Types are the same here.
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
```

There are techniques to make the above compact. If you are just started this may be a bit early for this, but for completness I will add it here:

```
bool found = std::find(std::begin(disliked), std::end(disliked), text[x]) != std::end(disliked);
if (!found) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have two options here:

**1. Get the input from a text file.**

In this case you have to place your data in a text file, in your project directory. For example, in the code posted below, "text.txt" is where the input should be stored (your words).

Minor remarks:
I'm not sure what "std_lib_facilities.h" contains so I added some of the standard headers to make the code compile for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> texts;
    std::string dislikedWord = "cat";

    std::ifstream fin("text.txt");

    for (std::string word; fin >> word;)
        texts.push_back(word);

    unsigned textsCount = texts.size();
    for (unsigned textIndex = 0; textIndex < textsCount; ++textIndex)
        if (texts[textIndex] != dislikedWord)
            std::cout << texts[textIndex] << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "BLEEP\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**2. Keep reading words until a condition is finally met.**

In this case (if you don't want to read from a text file) you should insert a condition that makes the program stop taking input, so you can preceed further. A condition can be something like maximum number of words that can be read or some 'special' word. In the example below, I chose to end reading at ten words.

Minor remarks: Maybe the chapter from where you got the exercise tells you what condition to insert. I doubt that you have to use CTRL+C or any other key combinations to solve the exercise.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const unsigned totalWords = 10;
    std::vector<std::string> texts;
    std::string dislikedWord = "cat";

    for (std::string word; std::cin >> word;) {
        texts.push_back(word);
        if (texts.size() == totalWords) // could've put it in the for condition
            break; // terminates the for-loop
    }

    unsigned textsCount = texts.size();
    for (unsigned textIndex = 0; textIndex < textsCount; ++textIndex)
        if (texts[textIndex] != dislikedWord)
            std::cout << texts[textIndex] << '\n';
        else
            std::cout << "BLEEP\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Super helpful too! Thanks :)